# Rephrase optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{z\in\mathbb{R},\, v\in\mathbb{R}^{d}}{\text{maximize}}
& & z \\
& \text{subject to}
& & z \geq \varepsilon,\\
& & & v \geq \varepsilon\mathbb{1},\\
& & & (zI+A)v \leq 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
for some (small) $\varepsilon>0$ and Metzler matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.

Note that there is a bilinear constraint in the optimization problem above. Can this problem be rephrased as a standard convex optimization problem, e.g. semidefinite programming, and simply solved by existing software?

Comment: Do you know something about the diagonal components of $A$? Are they also non-negative?

Comment: @Alex, no. They are arbitrary from my understanding. If certain cases are infeasible is not a problem here, it is expected that some $A$ will yield infeasible problems.

Comment: If the diagonal was positive, we would have a geometric problem, which can be reformulated as a convex problem. Otherwise, I do not know the answer, but I believe it cannot be done.

Comment: @Alex, okay. It was suggested using a bisection algorithm over the variable $z$ (and solving LPs in the intermediate steps) in the paper I was reading where this problem comes from.

Comment: Bisection is the obvious and probably best approach. A convex reformulation does not look possible